# Slow conversion of F# discriminated union case to string

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I have around 100k discriminated union cases I have to convert to strings, but it seems to be extremely slow.

As a comparison, the following executes (in F# interactive) in 3seconds on average :

```
open System

let buf = Text.StringBuilder()
let s = DateTime.Now

for i in 1 .. 100000 do
  Printf.bprintf buf "%A" "OtherFinancingInterest" //string
  buf.Length <- 0

printfn "elapsed : %0.2f" (DateTime.Now - s).TotalMilliseconds
```

While the following executes (also in F# interactive) in over a minute...

```
open System

let buf = Text.StringBuilder()
let s = DateTime.Now

for i in 1 .. 100000 do
  Printf.bprintf buf "%A" OtherFinancingInterest //DU
  buf.Length <- 0

printfn "elapsed : %0.2f" (DateTime.Now - s).TotalMilliseconds
```

The discriminated union has 25 values (the result is still extremely slow, around 16 seconds with two cases, but less so than with 25). Any idea if that is "normal" or if I may be doing something wrong ?

Many thanks

Comment: In F# interactive you can time things much more easily with `#time "on"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%A` format specifier pretty prints any F# value. It uses reflection to do so. It should only really be used for debugging purposes, and not in normal application code.

Note that using `%s` in your first example using a string makes it a lot faster because there is no type checking needed at runtime.

For the DU, there is a hack you could use to make the reflection only happen once on application load:

```
type FinancingInterest =
    | OtherFinancingInterest

open FSharp.Reflection
let private OtherFinancingInterestStringMap =
    FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<FinancingInterest>
    |> Array.map (fun c -> FSharpValue.MakeUnion(c, [||]) :?> FinancingInterest)
    |> Array.map (fun x -> x, sprintf "%A" x)
    |> Map.ofArray

type FinancingInterest with
    member this.AsString = OtherFinancingInterestStringMap |> Map.find this
```

You would also use this with the `%s` format specifier:

```
Printf.bprintf buf "%s" OtherFinancingInterest.AsString
```

I had similar timings to yours in your example, and now this one comes down to 40ms.

This only works as long as all of the DU cases don't have an arguments. You will get an exception on application load as soon as you try anything like this:

```
type FinancingInterest =
    | Foo of string
    | OtherFinancingInterest
```

Having said all this, I think you're better off writing a simple function that explicitly converts your type into a string value, writing out the names in full with repetition if necessary. The names of discriminated union cases should not generally be thought of as data that affects your program. You would usually expect to be able to safely rename case names without affecting runtime behaviour at all.

Comment: If the type is defined in a [recursive namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/namespaces#recursive-namespaces) (available from F# 4.1 onwards), you may in fact override `FinancingInterest.ToString()` using the suggested method, rather than extending the type. This will allow you to call `Printf.bprintf buf "%O" OtherFinancingInterest` (notice `%O` instead of `%A`) with the same performance as in @TheQuickBrownFox's answer.

Comment: @torbonde The thing I don't like about that `ToString()` and `%O` is that it becomes difficult to work out where in a codebase your override is being used. I've run into this problem before. If you use an explicitly named member you can find all usages and know what effect your change to a string representation will have. It also helps you split out different string representations for different use cases.

Comment: I see what you mean, that definitely makes sense. A different (partial) solution to this issue, is to have a static, bijective mapping between DU case and string, not relying on reflection. In this case, renaming a DU case won't affect the string representation. This is helpful when mapping string-values (from a database, say) to types and vice versa.